# unable to give static IP to my machine

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, ethernet, ip

I have an issue while assigning static IP to my Machine.
I am new to this forum and in Linux world as well, just now I installed Ubuntu Desktop LTS 14.04 on Virtual Machine.
When I checked `ifconfig` in terminal it outputs:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:70:91:81  
      inet addr:192.168.163.129  Bcast:192.168.163.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe70:9181/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:115 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:30180 (30.1 KB)  TX bytes:19458 (19.4 KB)
      Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:167 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:167 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:13170 (13.1 KB)  TX bytes:13170 (13.1 KB)
```

and when I checked in `/etc/network/interfaces` file it contains:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I guess eth0 is missing in this file, so how should i go
Please guide me , any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: 1) You can set a static IP in Network Manager. 2) I see no reason to set a static IP for a virtual machine.

Comment: Hi Pilot6 , Thanks for prompt reply .i need static ip as i am going to install media server plex and owncloud . and how to set static ip in network manger .

Comment: Anyway the virtual machine will use the network connection of the host system. You can set a static IP in a VM in NM, and set the VirtualBox to use bridge instead of NAT.

Comment: Hi Pilot , underneath of Ubuntu , window server 2008 is installed and having static ip 192.168.1.6,  but when i checked in Ubuntu its showing different that is 192.168.163.129

Comment: It looks that you do not know how networks are configured at all. It will be hard to explain. I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To set a static IP in Network Manager click the network icon on top of the screen, select "Edit connetions", then select your connection and press "Edit". You will see this screen (select IPV4 tab):

[image]

Select "Method" as "Manual" and add the required information.

To be able to connect directly from outside, you will need to change VB network settings from NAT to bridge:

[image]

You also need to be sure that the static IP is within the network range of the outside network. And set the available gateway correctly too.